# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x8C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I know this question is asked many times. But unfortunately I did not get any solution at such question.

My problem is when I do `rails s`, I am getting the below error. Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong with this.

Application ENV: `rails 3.2.13` and `ruby 1.9.3`.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-07-05 18:34:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-07-05 18:34:37] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-01-15) [i686-linux]
[2014-07-05 18:34:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=30168 port=3000
[2014-07-05 18:34:42] ERROR Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x8C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:58:in `write'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:58:in `<<'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:58:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:133:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/log.rb:71:in `error'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:98:in `rescue in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:113:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Looks like it has to do with the logging...it does actually start the server on port 3000. Have you checked into issues with logging and Webrick??

Comment: @Justin Yes, I checked but didn't get any clue why it's happening.

Comment: I know this is *not* a solution, but have you tried [Thin server](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)? Does `Thin` have the same issue with logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing `Thin server`, all errors are gone. I didn't understand what was the exact issue. Why it get work after installing `Thin server` .